# Plot PDF and CDF

Tags: data-visualization

I want to plot the probability density function and the cumulative distribution function for the gamma, lognormal, exponential and Pareto distribution. I want to vary the parameters and and have a plot with 2-3 different parameters in the same figure. It should look like this (example weibull distribution):

[Weibull_PDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aWeibull_PDF.svg)

```
library(Cairo)
CairoFonts(regular="DejaVu Sans:style=Regular")
CairoSVG("Weibull PDF.svg")
par(mar=c(3, 3, 1, 1))
x <- seq(0, 2.5, length.out=1000)
plot(x, dweibull(x, .5), type="l", col="blue", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(0, 2.5), ylim=c(0, 2.5), xaxs="i", yaxs="i")
lines(x, dweibull(x, 1), type="l", col="red")
lines(x, dweibull(x, 1.5), type="l", col="magenta")
lines(x, dweibull(x, 5), type="l", col="green")
legend("topright", legend=paste("\u03bb = 1, k =", c(.5, 1, 1.5, 5)), lwd=1, col=c("blue", "red", "magenta", "green"))
dev.off()
```

and

[Weibull_CDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aWeibull_CDF.svg)

```
library(Cairo)
CairoFonts(regular="DejaVu Sans:style=Regular")
CairoSVG("Weibull CDF.svg")
par(mar=c(3, 3, 1, 1))
x <- seq(0, 2.5, length.out=1000)
plot(x, pweibull(x, .5), type="l", col="blue", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(0, 2.5), ylim=c(0, 1), xaxs="i", yaxs="i")
lines(x, pweibull(x, 1), type="l", col="red")
lines(x, pweibull(x, 1.5), type="l", col="magenta")
lines(x, pweibull(x, 5), type="l", col="green")
legend("bottomright", legend=paste("\u03bb = 1, k =", c(.5, 1, 1.5, 5)), lwd=1, col=c("blue", "red", "magenta", "green"))
dev.off()
```

How do I adapt the syntax to use it for the other distributions?

Comment: Ehrm. Replace *weibull with *gamma and fill out the correct parameters? What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: If I'm having only one parameter for a distribution how do I change the syntax? Also, how do I change the legend, so that I have only one column with different values? How do I change the legends if I want to have two column with different entries? Right now, one column always has the entry 1.

Comment: You are right. Can somebody move it or should I just repost there?

Comment: although it appears that there are two columns, think of it more as a single column. it's produced by the `legend=paste(...)` statement. to get rid of the $\lambda$ in the legend, simply delete the `\u03bb = 1, ` part of the `legend` statement.

Comment: RTFM! The syntax for distributions is very clear in R, as are the basic plot commands. Just read the help(plot) and help(gamma) entries.